# React + TypeScript validation conditional props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having problems with validating props in the isLink function.

It is not enough to guarantee that props is LinkProps.

I searched the web, chatGPT and Bard and didn't find an answer.

Can you help me?

```
import { ComponentPropsWithoutRef, ReactNode } from "react";

type ButtonProps = ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button"> & {
  href?: never;
};

type LinkProps = ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"a"> & {
  href?: string;
};

type Props = (ButtonProps | LinkProps) & {
  children?: ReactNode;
};

function isLink(props: Props): props is LinkProps {
  return "href" in props;
}

function Button(props: Props) {
  const { children, className, ...rest } = props;

  if (isLink(rest)) {
    return (
      <a
        className={`${className ? `button ${className}` : `button`}`}
        {...rest}
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button
      className={`${className ? `button ${className}` : `button`}`}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: You need to explain better what is it that you want to do. It's pretty unclear.